# Store chat history in xmpp server in rails web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmpp

**I am using xmpp4r gem and i don't know how to get my chat history from xmpp server or don't know how to store all messages in mysql db.**

Comment: How to log messages server-side is specific to the XMPP server software you are using, but you don't mention which one that is.